# Troubleshooting composer: classes not autoloading with CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, autoload

**Problem**

I am trying to use the PayPal Checkout REST SDK which requires the PayPal library to be autoloaded through composer. I have gone through the steps to enable Composer in CodeIgniter 3 but when I go to my controller where I am autoloading the `PayPal\Rest\ApiContext` class I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\toucan-talk\App\modules\paypal\controllers\Paypal.php
>   on line 15

**What I have so far**

Here is my composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "*"
    }
}
```

I have set `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;` in my config.php file.

Here is my controller

```
<?php

use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;

class Paypal extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $api = new ApiContext(

        );
        var_dump($api);
    }

}
```

**Question**

How do I troubleshoot composer and its autoloader so that I can pinpoint where the autoload process is failing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well here is the solution: in config.php instead of setting...

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

You need to put

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

however I am still not certain why this works as opposed to the original documentations recommendation. Bit of a headache really.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer it helped me a lot. Apparently if you install your vendor folder in /application/vendor it works with composer_autoload = TRUE but if you put it on your root folder for example then it needs the full path :)

Comment: Yo! Great workaround. Tried a lot with different things but this one really worked.

Comment: The true method only works when your vendor folder is inside application folder

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite an old Question but still, i want to put my input that basically CodeIgniter 3 specifically 3.1.6 have problem that when you do

```
 $config['composer_autload'] = TRUE:
```

then it won't work and doesn't autoload the files from vendor folder now there are 2 possible solutions for this one solution already mentioned by "Jethro Hazelhurst".

The other simple solution is that copy composer.json inside application folder and then run composer install from the application folder or just move vendor folder along with composer.json and composer.lock to the application folder and then this TRUE value will work properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use composer dump-autoload in command prompt. This will regenerate list of files to be included in the project.

Comment: Hi, so I did that and it is still not working, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is the paypal package included in that list?

Comment: No, it just returns 'Generating autoload files' and then goes back to the prompt. Apologies in advance for not mentioning that, I am very unfamiliar with the command line, hence the question.

Comment: Am I not missing the "PSR-4 AUTOLOAD" bit in my composer.json file?

Comment: I needed to put `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;` in my config.php file

Answer (score -1):

For anybody else that might have this issue.
Codeigniter 3 has third_party folder inside application, use that for putting vendor directory (vendor directory contains the libraries).

> composer.json (/composer.json)

*tell composer to use the vendor directory inside third_party folder to store libraries*

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "application/third_party/vendor"
},
```

> config.php (/application/config/config.php)

*Tell Codeigniter 3 to autoload all libraries from third_party/vendor folder*

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = APPPATH . 'third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
```

---

PS: **Autoloading All Libraries On Every Request could result into a slow website** if there are many dependencies and a moderate to heavy traffic site. Load libraries as needed if that is the case.

Comment: There's a huge misconception from CodeIgniter side that you seem to have fallen for. First of all, CodeIgniter does not *autoload*, it *preloads* classes, even though they call it autoloading. That leads to the next point: autoloading does not load all classes/libraries - it defines a way to know how to load them. It exactly "load[s] libraries as needed". What CI did is to reinvent the wheel with a Loader class, which actually makes the whole process slower and more confusing.

Comment: so you mean to say is if i autoload 20,000 libraries from github into my codeigniter project, it will not load any code if i don't use any of them in my codebase, but load them using autoload? Any sources?

Comment: Correct.  CI will load all classes/functions/helpers defined in `config/autoload.php`, you can see that here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/63d037565dd782795021dcbd3b1ca6f8c8a509e4/system/core/Loader.php#L1317. However, CI+composer (and composer in general), only loads classes on demand, as explained here: https://jinoantony.com/blog/how-composer-autoloads-php-files (see "How it works" section)

Comment: Or the comment here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2122#issuecomment-11923464 (CI dev calling it "**magic** autoloading" - which I guess is the source of the confusion).

Oh and the fact that there are 0 references (except one **test**) to the only two ways one can implement autoloading in PHP: [spl_autoload_register](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Abcit-ci%2FCodeIgniter+spl_autoload_register&type=code) or [__autoload](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Abcit-ci%2FCodeIgniter+__autoload&type=code).